# Video Chatting or Conferencing in Web Appllication

Tags: .net, video-streaming, videochat, video-conferencing

Can any one tell me what would be best suitable API or mediator for enabling video chatting/conferencing (live) in my web application (using .net technology)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) is supported in Chrome and Firefox (Opera?) and perfect for video conferencing. It is not a .net technology but I do not see any problem in using it in a .net environment since the browsers have native support for it.

Use `getUserMedia` to get the stream from camera.

Set up an `RTCPeerConnection` and send the stream through that connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is best suitable API for Video/Audio Chatting/Call or Conferencing in Web Appllication

https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/